# How to restart Raspberry PI every week

Tags: raspberry-pi

I want to restart my Raspberry PI once a week. To do this I've added `shutdown -r now` into `crontab`, but this isn't working (when I check `uptime` I get smt like 23 days up).

Commands that I did to edit `crontab`:

```
# log in as pi user via SSH
sudo -i
crontab -e
# in crontab:
0 5 * * 1 sudo shutdown -r now
```

When I'm checking `uptime` right now I get:

```
 13:52:16 up 23 days, 21:21,  1 user,  load average: 0.87, 0.92, 0.95
```

PS

I'm running **RaspBMC**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cron jobs are per default disabled in RaspBMC. You need to activate them under

```
Programs > Raspbmc Settings > System Configuration > Service Management > Cronjob Scheduler
```

And as a side note, instead of starting a new root shell with

```
sudo -i
crontab -e
```

you should just do:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

to edit the crontab file.